# iOS UITableView as DropDown

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to create a dropdown on top of UITableView. There are few things I can't get done:

1. Is there a way to bring selected cell to front?
2. How to animate cell extension, including positions of those who are below. This can be achieved using UITableViewRowAnimation, but this is not an option, because those animations are really bad.

Currently, I've managed to animate selectedCell frame, but other cells jumps instantly covering selected one.

```
-(void)toggleCellStateForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)path {
//Get selected cell
__block UITableViewCell *targetCell = [self cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];

//Copy frame
NSValue *previousFrame = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:targetCell.frame];

//Reload
[CATransaction setDisableActions:YES];
[super reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[path] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
targetCell = [self cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];

//Remove previous animations
for (int x = 0; x < [self numberOfRowsInSection:0]; x++) {
    NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:x inSection:0];
    __block UITableViewCell *cell = [self cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];
    [cell pop_removeAllAnimations];
}

//Animate selected cell
POPSpringAnimation *spring = [POPSpringAnimation animationWithPropertyNamed:kPOPViewFrame];
spring.fromValue = previousFrame;
spring.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:targetCell.frame];
spring.springBounciness = 10;
spring.springSpeed = 14;
spring.removedOnCompletion = YES;
[targetCell pop_addAnimation:spring forKey:@"cellSpringAnimation"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will create a copy of the selectedCell,and animate it.

```
UITableViewCell *snapshotCell = [targetCell snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:YES];
targetCell.alpha = 0;
```

then animate other cell by controlling the targetCell.